# Final plot in a series of matplotlib subplots has increased y tick label padding

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I have a Pandas dataframe that contains columns representing year, month within year and a binary outcome (0/1). I want to plot a column of barcharts with one barchart per year. I've used the subplots() function in matplotlib.pyplot with sharex = True and sharey = True. The graphs look fine except the padding between the y-ticks and the y-tick labels is different on the final (bottom) graph.

An example dataframe can be created as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Generate dataframe containing dates over several years and a random binary outcome
tempDF = pd.DataFrame()
tempDF['date'] = pd.date_range(start = pd.to_datetime('2014-01-01'),end = pd.to_datetime('2017-12-31'))
tempDF['case'] = np.random.choice([0,1],size = [len(tempDF.index)],p = [0.9,0.1])

# Create a dataframe that summarises proportion of cases per calendar month
tempGroupbyCalendarMonthDF = tempDF.groupby([tempDF['date'].dt.year,tempDF['date'].dt.month]).agg({'case': sum,
                                                                                                   'date': 'count'})
tempGroupbyCalendarMonthDF.index.names = ['year','month']
tempGroupbyCalendarMonthDF = tempGroupbyCalendarMonthDF.reset_index()

# Rename columns to something more meaningful
tempGroupbyCalendarMonthDF = tempGroupbyCalendarMonthDF.rename(columns = {'case': 'numberCases',
                                                                          'date': 'monthlyTotal'})

# Calculate percentage positive cases per month
tempGroupbyCalendarMonthDF['percentCases'] = (tempGroupbyCalendarMonthDF['numberCases']/tempGroupbyCalendarMonthDF['monthlyTotal'])*100
```

The final dataframe looks something like:

```
    year  month  monthlyTotal  numberCases  percentCases
0   2014      1            31            5     16.129032
1   2014      2            28            5     17.857143
2   2014      3            31            3      9.677419
3   2014      4            30            1      3.333333
4   2014      5            31            4     12.903226
..   ...    ...           ...          ...           ...
43  2017      8            31            2      6.451613
44  2017      9            30            2      6.666667
45  2017     10            31            3      9.677419
46  2017     11            30            2      6.666667
47  2017     12            31            1      3.225806
```

Then the plots are produced as shown below. The subplots() function is used to return an array of axes. The code steps through each axis and plots the values. The x-axis ticks and labels are only displayed on the final (bottom) plot. Finally, the get a common y-axis label, an additional subplot is added that covers all the bar graphs but all the axes and labels (except the y axis label) are not displayed.

```
# Calculate minimumn and maximum years in dataset
minYear = tempDF['date'].min().year
maxYear = tempDF['date'].max().year

# Set a few parameters
barWidth = 0.80
labelPositionX = 0.872
labelPositionY = 0.60

numberSubplots = maxYear - minYear + 1

fig, axArr = plt.subplots(numberSubplots,figsize = [8,10],sharex = True,sharey = True)

# Keep track of which year to plot, starting with first year in dataset.
currYear = minYear

# Step through each subplot
for ax in axArr:

    # Plot the data
    rects = ax.bar(tempGroupbyCalendarMonthDF.loc[tempGroupbyCalendarMonthDF['year'] == currYear,'month'],
                   tempGroupbyCalendarMonthDF.loc[tempGroupbyCalendarMonthDF['year'] == currYear,'percentCases'],
                   width = barWidth)

    # Format the axes
    ax.set_xlim([0.8,13])
    ax.set_ylim([0,40])

    ax.grid(True)

    ax.tick_params(axis = 'both',
                   left = 'on',
                   bottom = 'off',
                   top = 'off',
                   right = 'off',
                   direction = 'out',
                   length = 4,
                   width = 2,
                   labelsize = 14)

    # Turn on the x-axis ticks and labels for final plot only
    if currYear == maxYear:
        ax.tick_params(bottom = 'on')
        xtickPositions = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]
        ax.set_xticks([x + barWidth/2 for x in xtickPositions])
        ax.set_xticklabels(['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec'])

    ytickPositions = [10,20,30]
    ax.set_yticks(ytickPositions)

    # Add label (in this case, the year) to each subplot
    # (The transform = ax.transAxes makes positios relative to current axis.)
    ax.text(labelPositionX, labelPositionY,currYear,
            horizontalalignment = 'center',
            verticalalignment = 'center',
            transform = ax.transAxes,
            family = 'sans-serif',
            fontweight = 'bold',
            fontsize = 18,
            color = 'gray')

    # Onto the next year...
    currYear = currYear + 1

# Fine-tune overall figure
# ========================
# Make subplots close to each other.
fig.subplots_adjust(hspace=0)

# To display a common y-axis label, create a large axis that covers all the subplots
fig.add_subplot(111, frameon=False)

# Hide tick and tick label of the big axss
plt.tick_params(labelcolor='none', top='off', bottom='off', left='off', right='off')

# Add y label that spans several subplots
plt.ylabel("Percentage cases (%)", fontsize = 16, labelpad = 20)

plt.show()
```

[image: Example plot produce by code showing problem with y-tick labels on final plot]

The figure that is produced is almost exactly what I want but the y-axis tick labels on the bottom plot are set further from the axis compared with all the other plots. If the number of plots produced is altered (by using a wider range of dates), the same pattern occurs, namely, it's only the final plot that appears different.

I'm almost certainly not seeing the wood for the trees but can anyone spot what I've done wrong?

**EDIT**
The above code was original run on Matplotlib 1.4.3 (see comment by ImportanceOfBeingErnest). However, when updated to the Matplotlib 2.0.2 the code failed to run (KeyError: 0). The reason appears to be that the default setting in Matplotlib 2.xxx is for bars to be aligned center. To get the above code to run, either adjust the x-axis range and tick positions so that the bars don't extend beyond the y-axis or set align='center' in the plotting function, i.e.:

```
rects = ax.bar(tempGroupbyCalendarMonthDF.loc[tempGroupbyCalendarMonthDF['year'] == currYear,'month'],
                       tempGroupbyCalendarMonthDF.loc[tempGroupbyCalendarMonthDF['year'] == currYear,'percentCases'],
                       width = barWidth,
                       align = 'edge')
```

Comment: Could it be that something gets reset in this line: `ax.tick_params(bottom = 'on')`? What if you add there all the options you set earlier?

Comment: Using matplotlib 2.0 I cannot reproduce this issue. All labels appear as desired.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest - Updating eventually resolved the issue but it wasn't straight forward. Initially, the plots failed with KeyError 0. It turned out that the default behaviour of ax.bar() in matplotlib 2.xx is align='center'. The plots would only plot if align was set to 'edge' (or if tick positions were adjusted). This may partly explain the original problem. The extra padding may have been an artefact caused by the fact that the unadjusted bar position for January extended slightly beyond the y axis.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest – just for the record, I submitted a bug report to matplotlib github to deal with the the problem associated with align='center' option. More detals at https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/8767.